# Need of Image Encryption

Tags: encryption, aes, implementation, des, visual-cryptography

Question is simple yet confusing, why there is the need for image encryption. How text encryption is different from image encryption if using same technique like AES, DES, Chaotic algorithm. If the only difference is at implementation it's more of engineering task than science. Can same encryption technique applied to both text and image, then why image encryption a separate part.

Comment: What leads you to believe that image encryption is a separate thing? Can you cite some sources? That would help us know specifically what you are talking about.

Comment: Because non cryptographers want to feel like they can create crypto too?

Comment: I think and believe that they are the same thing, the only difference is implementation. But when I see research papers with title image encryption using AES or DES or Novel approach, seems confusing, why just image, when it can be applied to other data too. Just curious. Thanks for reply.

Comment: @PawanYadav Your confusion is justified - "image encryption" is generally the hallmark of "cranks" who don't really understand what they're doing/talking about. There is no reason you can't apply an arbitrary encryption algorithm to a given subsection of an arbitrary file.

Comment: @EllaRose Thanks for the reply. So, that means it's merely an engineering task to use that algorithm (where actual science is applied), to perform a particular task i.e. different data types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need for those image encryption algorithms.

- You can encrypt an image file, like any other sequence of bytes using standard encryption.
- If you really want to encrypt the pixels themselves (not recommended), you can use standard length preserving encryption, such as a four round feistel network.

I've seen some image encryption papers, but they were badly written by people with little understanding of cryptography and not published in cryptography journals/conferences.